# How to get parent class from inner var in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, browser

**I have class like this**

```
class Game {
    constructor(player1, player2, gameId) {

        this.Clockk = {
            totalSeconds: timeForAnswer,
            nowSeconds: timeForAnswer,

            start: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                    self.nowSeconds -= 1;
                    if (self.nowSeconds == 0) {

                          here I want to call "answered" function

                    }
            },

            reset: function(){
                this.nowSeconds = this.totalSeconds;
            },
        };

        answered(player) {
             console.log(player);
        }
    };
```

I want to call function of `Game` class from `this.Clockk` variable.
`this` keyword inside a variable is `this.Clockk`itself, how can I get parrent class itself?

Comment: That code has at least a couple of syntax errors, could you make it correct (other than the call you don't know how to make) so we're not guessing at what you want to do?

Comment: If you have code like `const myGame = new Game();` then something like `myGame.answered();` will work. But in a better structure, the clock and the game won't be coupled to eachother in this way: The game could pass a callback into the clock that will get triggered once the clock reaches zero. Then the game runs the clock instead of the clock running parts of the game.

Comment: You can use arrow functions to keep the this context, but I often find there less flexibly than what you kind have already have done -> `var self = this;`  But to make this more robust you could do `var thisClockk  = this`, and you could do another one for your game, so first line of your constructor do `var thisGame = this`, there is now no confusion on what `this` you want to refer too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a method of the `Clockk` object, then `this` will refer to the `Clockk` object and, in Javascript, there is no natural way to refer to a "parent" or "containing" object.  So, you have to store a reference to the parent somewhere.  I can think of two straightforward ways to store it that come to mind.  One is to store it in the parent scope, the other is to store it in the instance data of the `Clockk` object itself.

FYI, I am also assuming that the `answered()` method is supposed to be a method on Game object (your code in your question doesn't quite show that - but that appears to be the intent).

Here are two ways to do be able to call the parent's `answered()` method from with the `this.Clockk.start()` method:

**Save parent reference in parent scope**

```
class Game {
    constructor(player1, player2, gameId) {

        // save parent reference here so child scopes can refer to it
        let parentObj = this;

        this.Clockk = {
            totalSeconds: timeForAnswer,
            nowSeconds: timeForAnswer,

            start: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                    self.nowSeconds -= 1;
                    if (self.nowSeconds == 0) {

                        // here I want to call "answered" function
                        parentObj.answered();

                    }
            },

            reset: function(){
                this.nowSeconds = this.totalSeconds;
            },
        };

    }
    answered(player) {
        console.log(player);
    }
}
```

**Save parent reference in `Clockk` instance data**

```
class Game {
    constructor(player1, player2, gameId) {

        this.Clockk = {
            // save parent reference in our own instance data
            parent: this,     
            totalSeconds: timeForAnswer,
            nowSeconds: timeForAnswer,

            start: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                    self.nowSeconds -= 1;
                    if (self.nowSeconds == 0) {

                        // here I want to call "answered" function
                        self.parent.answered();

                    }
            },

            reset: function(){
                this.nowSeconds = this.totalSeconds;
            },
        };

    }
    answered(player) {
        console.log(player);
    }
}
```

Or, you could break the `Clockk` implementation out into it's own `class` definition and then you'd pass the parent to it in its constructor and then its constructor would store the parent reference in its own instance data.

Comment: +1 for effort, just wish they'd create a separate class for `Clock` rather than nesting its declaration in the constructor of another class.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Nesting has some advantages such as the first option I show can only be used when it's nested.  But, I generally understand and agree with your comment.  In that case, you'd probably pass the parent object to the constructor when you created the `Clockk` object.

Comment: @Bakurits Separating the classes has less "code smell" and provides more optimization since the member methods of `Clock` can be shared rather than re-declared for each instance of `Game`. Just my two cents.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I don't disagree, but can we perhaps stay on-topic here?  That isn't what this question is about.